# VBA O365 Mac Excel copy and Word PasteSpecial with links = True problem

Tags: excel, vba, macos, ms-word

I'm on *Excel 16.32* and I'm **rewriting old windows VBA to convert it for Mac** use instead (want to close our terminal server).

I have no problem with open and save files (sandboxing) and have got the most working. But the big issue is that I can’t get the `pastespecial` with `link:=true` to work.

- Excel - copy cell/range - in this case cell B2.
- Word - paste it in bookmark ”FastBetRubr” with link so it can be updated if needed.

So:

```
myDoc.Bookmarks.Item("FastBetRubr").Range.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteText, Placement:=wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False, Link:=False
```

**Is working**

But:

```
myDoc.Bookmarks.Item("FastBetRubr").Range.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteText, Placement:=wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False, Link:=True
```

**Is not working** and gives a *5345 error* (no use error code).

We really need the links and if I make a break-point and then paste-special in word it works. It also works if just tries to paste-special normally.

The files are on a SMB share and I have tried to save both documents before *pastespecial* and *without saving -* no change.

**Is this still a sandboxing error or is the Excel-Word pasting not working in Mac O365 ?**

Comment: I don't know waht you mean with "no user error code", but it would really help if you were to tell us the *error message* as no one memorizes what the numbers mean. Are you able to copy/Paste Special with a link as an end-user, through the Word UI? If yes, record a macro when doing that and see if it produces anything different from the code you have? Or a useful error?

Comment: I have tried to record a macro but it “is to complex to record” so it didn’t get recorded. The error just say: Run-time error '5345':

Word cannot obtain the data for the {00020832-0000-0000-C000-000000000046 link.

Comment: Linked Office files use OLE. In macOS, OLE doesn't exist in the OS, so Microsoft created a custom port of the technology just for Office for Mac. As you've found, the implementation is limited, buggy and undocumented.

Comment: I agree. It's also very slow. I hope that Microsoft understand that a lot of companies are switching to Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It looks like an error (bug) in Mac Word. Either that, or Microsoft doesn't think people should be working with unencoded text on Mac. I get the same here on v16.31, and the same problem (with dialog box) when attempting to Paste Special with Link using *text* format.
2. Here, I can make it work by inserting the Link using the Unformatted Unicode Text option. To do that, use

   ```
   myDoc.Bookmarks.Item("FastBetRubr").Range.PasteSpecial DataType:=22, Placement:=wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False, Link:=True
   ```
3. Microsoft does not seem to have maintained the wdPasteDataType enumeration, so there is no built-in constant such as "wdUnicodeText" that you can use instead of the "22"
4. In this case, Word inserts a LINK field with an additional \u switch that specifies the Unicode encoding. If you remove that switch and try to update the field, you see an error message that suggests that Word can't find the file.

Comment: BIG thanks!! That solved it. I have spent hours and hours trying differens solutions but that made it! Where can I find the other DataTypes (for charts etc)? It's sad that then don't use the normal built-in constants.

Comment: IMO the best place to look for named constants is in the VB Editor under View->Object Browser.